# Invoking Shell Script from build.gradle

Tags: shell, amazon-dynamodb, build.gradle

I am trying to invoke shell script that will create tables in dynamo DB before executing the tests.I have below task written in my build.gradle.

```
task runShellScript(type: Exec) {
    doFirst{
        println 'running Shell Script'
        exec{
//          commandLine 'chmod','+x','remote-dev/remotedev.sh'
            executable = 'chmod +x'
            args = ['remote-dev/remotedev.sh']
        }
    }
    executable = 'sh'
    args = ['remote-dev/remotedev.sh -m install']
//  commandLine 'sh', 'remote-dev/remotedev.sh -m install'
}

test.dependsOn runShellScript

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

When I run the build.gradle the script should create tables in DynamoDB before executing the tests.
But I am seeing below error.

> Task :runShellScript FAILED
> Caching disabled for task ':runShellScript' because:
> Build cache is disabled
> Task ':runShellScript' is not up-to-date because:
> Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
> running Shell Script
> Starting process 'command 'chmod +x''. Working directory: GitProjects\payments Command: chmod +x remote-dev/remotedev.sh
> :runShellScript (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.224 secs.

I am running ./gradlew clean build from windows but ultimately this will be part of jenkins pipeline so it has to execute both on windows and linux. Do I need to create .bat file for windows?
Any pointers?

thanks